# How to correct the pandas script to edit csv file - removing single quotes, adding double ones, deleting the unnecessary columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

Started learning pandas and maybe got lost with it so just need some assistance.

I am trying to automate a process for editing a csv file. I am receiving unsorted ones and trying to get them ready to go for some bulk updates.

So, what I need to do is:
1.Rename the needed columns (which I did okay)
2.Replace existing double quotes for two single ones in title column
3.Add double quotes to all the titles (that's first column)
4.drop columns (not sure what's best - del or df.drop)
5.Save changes to a new file somewhere defined

This is the code I have tried now and it worked with:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Sheet1.csv')
droped = df.drop(df.columns[[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]],axis = 1,inplace=True)
renamed = df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'title', df.columns[1]: 'product_id'})
swapped = renamed[[0]].str.replace(r'\"', r"\''")
updated = swapped.update('"' + df.columns[[0]].astype(str) + '"')

print(renamed.head())
```

These quotes are headache to me now - some titles have double quotes inside - I need to remove them and then add double quotes around every title.

First three lines work fine, I am able to drop the unnecessary columns and rename the remaining ones, but last two operations are not well written. I am trying to figure out googling around but no luck so far.

Example for this quote swap:

Now:Banini Movie" Teather
Desired:"Banini Movie'' Theater"

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/testing_scripts/bulk_script.py", line 6, in <module>
    swapped = renamed[[0]].str.replace(r'\"', r"\''")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3511, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5782, in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5842, in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's very difficult to test code without input or desired output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BeRT2me I have edited my comment with error and some changed code I have made. I have figured how to drop and rename, but this quote thins is killing me, honestly :D haha any assistance or guidance is appreciated

Comment: Maybe I am mistaking in defining variables here, not sure, to be honest.

Comment: Are the only columns you want to read `0` and `1` from the CSV?

Comment: That's right. Usually, I only need those.  If some other is needed, I can leave it when dropping. @BeRT2me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you just have a typo.

```
# Here, you rename your columns:
renamed = df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'title', df.columns[1]: 'product_id'})
# Here, you try to access the column by its old name...
renamed[[0]]
> None of [Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]
# This error is correct, only 'title' and 'product_id' are in 'columns'.

# What it could be:
renamed['title']

# Or to access by col #:
renamed.iloc[:, 0]
```

---

1. Reading in Specific Columns:

```
from io import StringIO 
# StringIO just allows me to treat a string like a file, 
# you'll use your file name in read_csv instead.
import pandas as pd

file = '0,1,2,3,4\nsr,ddpi,np.log(dpi),pop75,np.log(pop15)\nnp.log(pop15),sr,ddpi,np.log(dpi),pop75\npop75,np.log(pop15),sr,ddpi,np.log(dpi)\nnp.log(dpi),pop75,np.log(pop15),sr,ddpi\nddpi,np.log(dpi),pop75,np.log(pop15),sr\n'

print(pd.read_csv(StringIO(file)))
print(pd.read_csv(StringIO(file), usecols=[0,1]))
```

Output, we can see that by using the keyword `usecols` we can filter for the columns we want when reading the file, instead of having to drop them later:

```
               0              1              2              3              4
0             sr           ddpi    np.log(dpi)          pop75  np.log(pop15)
1  np.log(pop15)             sr           ddpi    np.log(dpi)          pop75
2          pop75  np.log(pop15)             sr           ddpi    np.log(dpi)
3    np.log(dpi)          pop75  np.log(pop15)             sr           ddpi
4           ddpi    np.log(dpi)          pop75  np.log(pop15)             sr

               0              1
0             sr           ddpi
1  np.log(pop15)             sr
2          pop75  np.log(pop15)
3    np.log(dpi)          pop75
4           ddpi    np.log(dpi)
```

Also, an alternative method of 'dropping' columns, when what your really want is to just keep a couple columns is doing:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file))
df = df[['0', '1']]
print(df)
```

```
               0              1
0             sr           ddpi
1  np.log(pop15)             sr
2          pop75  np.log(pop15)
3    np.log(dpi)          pop75
4           ddpi    np.log(dpi)
```

---

2. Renaming columns when you know their order:

```
# Personally, I find these methods to be simpler for the case you've presented~

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file), usecols=[0,1])
df.columns = ['title', 'product_id']

# OR
# If your file doesn't have a header, then remove 'header=0'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file), usecols=[0,1], header=0, names=['title', 'product_id'])

print(df)
```

```
           title     product_id
0             sr           ddpi
1  np.log(pop15)             sr
2          pop75  np.log(pop15)
3    np.log(dpi)          pop75
4           ddpi    np.log(dpi)
```

---

3. Changing up the quotes, and putting it all together:

```
file = '0,1,2,3,4\nsr,Banini Movie" Teather,np.log(dpi),pop75,np.log(pop15)\nnp.log(pop15),sr,ddpi,np.log(dpi),pop75\npop75,Banini Movie" Teather,sr,ddpi,np.log(dpi)\nBanini Movie" Teather,pop75,Banini Movie" Teather,sr,ddpi\nddpi,np.log(dpi),pop75,Banini Movie" Teather,sr\n'

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file), usecols=[0,1], header=0, names=['title', 'product_id'])
print(df)
```

```
                   title             product_id
0                     sr  Banini Movie" Teather
1          np.log(pop15)                     sr
2                  pop75  Banini Movie" Teather
3  Banini Movie" Teather                  pop75
4                   ddpi            np.log(dpi)
```

```
# To do it to one column:
df['title'] = df['title'].str.replace('"', "''")
df['title'] = '"' + df['title'] + '"'
print(df)
```

```
                      title             product_id
0                      "sr"  Banini Movie" Teather
1           "np.log(pop15)"                     sr
2                   "pop75"  Banini Movie" Teather
3  "Banini Movie'' Teather"                  pop75
4                    "ddpi"            np.log(dpi)
```

```
# To do it to all columns:
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace('"', "''")
    df[col] = '"' + df[col] + '"'

print(df)
```

```
                      title                product_id
0                      "sr"  "Banini Movie'' Teather"
1           "np.log(pop15)"                      "sr"
2                   "pop75"  "Banini Movie'' Teather"
3  "Banini Movie'' Teather"                   "pop75"
4                    "ddpi"             "np.log(dpi)"
```

Comment: Wow, mate! Thank you for this one. I will check it out and try on our datasets here. Will get back with feedback

Comment: It works as hell! Thank you so much, learned a lot :)

Comment: If you feel like this sufficiently answered your question, please mark this answer as the accepted answer ~

Comment: I just have. Thanks!